# PB OLEObject is not populating methods of wscript.network

Tags: powerbuilder

Is there any installation issue in PowerBuilder 12.5 and higher version. The OLEObject is not populating wscript.network class related methods.

I am using windows 10 OS.

Please help anything do I need while installing ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The PowerBuilder installation process doesn't have anything to do with whether your attempts to use OLEObject to work with wscript are working or not.

What are you attempting to do?

Comment: It was not working when I was trying with Wscript, Later I got some solution internet, that was environment variable update on Path variable (MapXtreme Rastergridhandlers for WIN32 and WIN64) after this update the WScript started working. But when I was using MQ methods it was again not working.. can you help on this MQ method accessing via OLE? I am using IBM MQ WebSphere V7.5.0.2

Comment: Sorry, I have never used MQ.